# Watchdog: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor

Tags: python, operating-system, python-watchdog

So I have my code to move file from one folder to another.

```
import watchdog
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os
import json
import time
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            src = folder_to_track + "/" + filename
            new_destination = folder_destination + "/" + filename
            os.rename(src, new_destination)
folder_to_track = "/Folder"
folder_destination = "/Filmy"
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
      time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\Projects\pygame\file_mover.py", line 21, in <module>
    observer.start()
  File "C:\Users\Marek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 256, in start
    emitter.start()
  File "C:\Users\Marek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\watchdog\utils\__init__.py", line 93, in start
    self.on_thread_start()
  File "C:\Users\Marek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\watchdog\observers\read_directory_changes.py", line 67, in on_thread_start
    self._handle = get_directory_handle(self.watch.path)
  File "C:\Users\Marek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 316, in get_directory_handle
    return CreateFileW(path, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, WATCHDOG_FILE_SHARE_FLAGS,
  File "C:\Users\Marek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 112, in _errcheck_handle
    raise ctypes.WinError()
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor.
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Please explain more about what you are trying to do and how your program is failing to do that. What is the intended result? How does your program attempt to obtain that result?

Comment: It is actually code from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbW6FRbaSl0 the first project. I just do little bit research what should which library do, but I wanted to figure out the logic behind it after I run it.

Comment: I am just prompting you to add more information because it will be easier for people to help you if you do. It looks like you do not have the needed files in place to support the code. I would check that first.

Comment: My local machine has installed python version 3.10.2.It is working fine with the same code above. But I am getting the same error above when I try to run this code in python version 3.10.5. @user3 Are you able to fix the issue?